# Home Electricity - What kind of outlet box is this

Tags: electrical, receptacle

**Scenario**

One of the 110v outlet boxes in our home had a "sagging" faceplate. It turned out that the screws for the plate didn't have a traditional threads to screw into. Upon further investigation the box has two spots (top and bottom) for an unusual sized plastic-nut insert, a black plastic about 1cm W x 1cm H x 2.5 cm L with threads along the inside length of the piece.

**Question**

What type of unusual outlet box is this? I'd like to find this replacement plastic piece so that I can position the faceplate correctly as the box itself is securely in place.

*Notes*

- We are in a townhome which is part of a larger hoa of similar homes so this piece may be proprietary based on some sort of contract with the developer
- Since finding this I've noticed problems with a couple other faceplates where these plastic pieces are also broken / stripped

** EDIT **

Here's a video of the box

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXKGsXi-oTk

Screenshot of box where insert should go:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Any chance of a picture?  Also, what country?  Language makes me think US, but then you gave metric measurements.  Electric varies a lot based on location.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll snag a photo next chance I get. Yes western US so maybe 1/4" x 1/4" x 1" ish dimensions

Comment: I added a video to the question - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXKGsXi-oTk

Comment: As far as your developer comment… yea, it would seem the electrical contractors they used got talked into buying this system to save install time. I bet there’s a few neighborhoods in your town that have to deal with this.  They would only save money if they bought in bulk and trained their installers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those outlet boxes are the Leviton Cheetah line of “quick install” boxes.  The outlets and covers just push into place when first installing, but as you have discovered, the plastic inserts can break over time or when you try to remove and reinstall the outlets.

[Cheetah box inserts](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08KHYZH4X/)

[image: inserts]

You can buy replacement inserts.  I would shop around.  That Amazon listing seems high, and I didn’t look around further than that.

Found a PDF with more info and smug pictures of contractors that save time and money with the system:  [Leviton Cheetah Brochure](https://www.cesco.com/resources/pdf_B0C/58574-Catalog.pdf)

Comment: I'd never heard of these so I just googled them. Found a thread of some electricians suggesting that these will all eventually fail in this manner. Their advice is to use epoxy to glue those inserts in place more permanently. Also the Leviton part number is 4000-C00

Comment: I see the merit of in for installers, but after the fact, a simple receptacle or light switch replacement that should take 5 min and cost a few bucks turns into replacing the entire box with a remodel box because you’re not going to find anyone that sells the special plates and connectors.

Comment: Ugh. I also haven't had the pleasure of meeting these in person. Not a bit surprised these are no longer available. Aside to the OP: these look to be backstabbed, which isn't ideal.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate they don’t have time to screw on a faceplate, they’re not going to screw down wires!  It’s all push and go.

Comment: At $3ea on amazon this is a fine opportunity for some 3d printing

Comment: @Jacksonkr, For what its worth, I doubt the drywall screws you found were OEM, and could have caused it to break more.  Look for a finer thread screw of the right size if you buy replacement inserts or make your own.  3D printing is one idea, but I could also see making some small wooden blocks pre-drilled for a screw and glued in place as an option thats more accessible for most people.

Comment: Those wood screws are definitely not oem. A sibling was living in that room for a bit and I suspect they had something to do with the wood screws. I'll probably just break some toothpicks and jam them in there until the screw grabs.

Comment: Or for the same price or probably less, you could easily replace the box, outlet, and faceplate with more common standard parts.

Comment: Replacement would be the next step for sure. I glued the plastic insert back together yesterday, today I put it in place and jammed in a toothpick on each side to add pressure incase the piece broke again. Since I'm using wood screws it broke as expected but the toothpicks did their job - the plate is back on and as snug as ever. Thanks all!